# Why is "pip install -U --no-deps PyBERT" failing, in the setup.py file of one of PyBERT's dependencies?

Tags: pip, anaconda, enthought, traitsui, chaco

One of my users is reporting the following failure, when attempting to update the *PyBERT* package, using:

```
pip install -U --no-deps PyBERT

> Requirement already up-to-date: pybert in
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages Collecting traitsui (from pybert)  
> Using cached traitsui-5.1.0.zip Collecting chaco (from pybert)   Using
> cached chaco-4.6.0.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "c:\users\twesterh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yxql2k\chaco\setup.py",
> line 131, in <module>
>         write_version_py()
>       File "c:\users\twesterh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yxql2k\chaco\setup.py",
> line 111, in write_version_py
>         match = re.match(r'.*?\.dev(?P<dev_num>\d+)', full_v)
>     NameError: global name 'full_v' is not defined
```

Does anyone know:

1. Why is the "`pip install...`" process calling the *chaco* `setup.py` file, when pip has already decided to use the installed/cached version of chaco?
2. Where the global name, *full_v*, is normally defined?

My user reports that, if he uninstalls/reinstalls *PyBERT*, then everything works fine. Can anyone explain what subtle differences occur, for "`pip install -U {package}`", as compared to "`pip uninstall {package}`" / "`pip install {package}`"?

Please, note that *chaco* was installed with "`conda install chaco`", as opposed to "`pip install chaco`". I'm using mixed installation commands, because:

1. I find that I get better results, in general, when I give *conda* the first crack at new package installation.
2. *PyBERT* has not, yet, been registered in *conda-forge*.

Thanks!
-db